# Split bash script into separate commands and run them them one-by-one

Tags: python, bash, shell, subprocess, gtk

I want to be able to run a bash shell script from Python (using something like `subprocess.Popen`), but display on my GUI the command that will be executed along with the output live as it comes in `stdout` and `stderr`. The GUI should show `Input (newline) Output (newline) Input` and so on. I am able to currently implement it for one-line bash commands, but I need a more sophisticated parser for multi-line commands. Here is my code which only works for simple one-line commands in `bash`.

test.sh:

```
ping -c 2 www.google.com

if [ "abc" = "ghi" ]; then
    echo expression evaluated as true
else
    echo expression evaluated as false
fi
```

My python file:

```
with open("test.sh", "r") as script:
    for line in script:
        if not line.strip().startswith('#') and not line.strip() == "":
            print("Debug: Running " + line.strip() + " ...")
            proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(line), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
            while True:                        
                output = str(proc.stdout.readline().strip().decode()) + ""
                err = str(proc.stderr.readline().strip().decode()) + ""
                if output == '' and proc.poll() is not None:
                    print("Debug: Command completed...")
                    time.sleep(1)
                    break
                if output: 
                    # Code for updating a Gtk TextView buffer
                    GLib.idle_add(self.updateConsoleText, output + "\n")
                if err:
                    # Code for updating a Gtk TextView buffer
                    GLib.idle_add(self.updateConsoleText, err + "\n")
```

As expected, it does not work with multi-line code that involves `if-else`, `loops`, `heredoc`s, etc. I am looking for a `bash` parser that at least recognises when a command ends and can split a bash script into separate commands in such cases where multi-line commands are used.

Do you think you could help me find such a library/tool?

Comment: Depending on your needs, simply running the script with `bash -x` from your Python program might already do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the trap command.

Here a little example to demonstrate the concept:

```
#!/bin/bash

# redirect stderr to a logfile
exec 2>/tmp/test.log

# print commands and arguments at execution
set -x

# set trap for every step, sleep one second.
# "sleep 1" could be every bash command
trap "sleep 1" DEBUG

echo -n "Name: "; read -r name
echo -n "Age: "; read -r age
echo "$name is $age years old"
```

Parallel to the run of this script you can use `tail -f /tmp/test.log` to track the call of the commands and their parameters.

Comment: This is a simple solution! I just have to inject it into my scripts using Python. But I plan to use something like https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/430480/formatting-display-of-of-set-v-output.